# How to get OUTPUT parameter of stored procedure sp_setapprole in SQLServer

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using the following JDBC driver (the one from Microsoft): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx.

I want to retrieve the OUTPUT parameter (@cookie) of the stored procedure `sp_setapprole`. I can call the procedure fine like this, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the OUTPUT parameter.

```
statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute("EXEC sp_setapprole '" + applicationRoleName + "', '" + applicationRolePassword + "'");
```

I tried with a PreparedStatement and a CallableStatement and I always get the following exception: `Stored procedure 'sys.sp_setapprole' can only be executed at the ad hoc level.`. I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944693/1362049, but I don't like the solution (use another JDBC driver).

So my question: how to get OUTPUT parameter from stored procedure `sp_setapprole` in SQLServer using a `Statement`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help.  I am not a big java program but lived with ODBC for years.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-statements.htm

Look at the callable statement.  You need to define the in/out, or inout parameters.  Execute the SP and read the output.

In C#, it is just looking at the parameter such as below give you the value.  But the idea of making a connection, binding parameters, making the call and reading the output are the same.

my_Cmd.Parameters["@PageCount"].Value.ToString();

Here is a article from MSDN in C++.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403283.aspx

Same idea, bind parameters, make the call, read the output using [SQLExecDirect]

Give me a holler if you do not get it.

Comment: I can't use a CallableStatement (or PreparedStatement) because I get the error `Stored procedure 'sys.sp_setapprole' can only be executed at the ad hoc level.`. See my first post.